# LoadLibrary бросает исключение

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, dll

Пишу свой `.dll` файл, при импорте функций из библиотеки функция `LoadLibrary` выкидывает исключение о нарушении прав доступа при чтении.

```
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"win32px.dll"); // exception
```

`.dll` находится в папке вместе с `.exe`.

Текст исключения:

`Исключение по адресу 0x74AF16B0 (kernel32.dll) в WindowsProject4.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000.`

Судя по всему, функция пытается что-то считать из нулевого указателя, однако я не понимаю, почему так происходит. Что это за проблема и как ее можно устранить?

Comment: При вызове LoadLibrary - идет вызов DllMain из самой Dll, это означает что сама dll непосредственно выбрасывает исключение. Возможно она не совместима с вашей версией OS, возможно ей чего-то не хватает (файла, ключа реестра или ещё чего-то). Данную проблему никак нельзя решить если dll чужая. Если ваша - открывайте её исходник. Если чужая - попробуйте другие версии dll.

Comment: Вызов DllMain отменить теоретически можно, но тогда будете ловить исключения при любом обращении к даной dll.

Comment: @nick_n_a Проблема решилась, когда я использовал функцию `LoadLibraryEx` вместо `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Если вы отменили вызов DllMain  - то да. Других идей у меня нету, т.к. читая код kernel32.dll вижу что LoadLibrary делает проброс  на код LoadLibraryEx. Если у вас dll-ресурсов, или не страшно что DllMain пропущена - то проблем не будет. Если нет - то исключения получите чуть позже при обращении к функциям даной dll.